# PHP HTML Parsers (Are there just no good HTML parsers)

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have spent all day trying different PHP HTML Parsers for the purpose to web scraping.
They all handle Google.com great, or other similar example that they post of their homepage. But they all fail on "http://www.nhl.com/ice/schedulebyseason.htm".

Originally I had written a Perl script to do this. Web::Scraper on perl had absolutely no trouble. and I went back 5 minutes ago and it does the job perfectly. But my shared hosting does not really support Perl. And even for PHP I am stuck using 5.3.13, I think.

If you try to use:

1. PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
2. ganon

They fail.

PHP Simple throws a `Call to a member function find() on a non-object` exception when I try to use the returned parsed document. And I assume this is just how it fails, by returning null or whatever.

ganon just processed forever when given the URL.

What is going on? I am a complete novice on PHP.

PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Example:

```
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

 $doc = file_get_html('http://www.nhl.com/ice/schedulebyseason.htm');

 foreach($doc->find('img') as $img){
  echo $img->id . '<br>';
 }
```

Ganon:

```
include_once('ganon.php');

$doc = file_get_dom('http://www.nhl.com/ice/schedulebyseason.htm');
```

Comment: I have built various web scrapers with php and they do not fail at all. There must be errors within your code.

Comment: Did you verify the code you are getting returned. Look for errors or if they detected the scrapping and are returning junk code to you.

Comment: I did not. But in most cases nothing is returned to test. You can see the one line example for Ganon, it just runs until Maximum execution time is reached or I close the window (if I set_time_limit(0)). I cannot test for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony 2 framework has a pretty awesome parser

Check out [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html) & [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte)

You can install individual components using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) too.

Comment: They where my first try. They both require PHP versions higher than I am able get on my shared hosting account.

5.3.2 and 5.3.3 respectively, instead of my 5.3.13, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski 5.3.13 > 5.3.3